# Change Windows RRAS Server Protocol

Tags: windows-10, vpn, dial-up

I have a Windows 10 machine acting as an RRAS dial-in server. I also have an older machine which doesn't seem to support the RRAS protocol the Windows 10 machine is using. How can I change the RRAS protocol to an older one?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer from [external site](http://www.mac-forums.com/os-x-operating-system/8466-mac-dial-windows-rras-tips.html) copy and pasted here:

For those out there experiencing problems with this, trying to connect a Mac running any OS X version to a Windows Server running RRAS, I have some info that may be of help.

I noted online that Mac's prefer to use standard CHAP (MD5) encryption, while CHAP is not enabled on Windows Servers by default. So... I had to get access to the administrator of my Windows Server and ask them to enable the checkbox under Properties of Routing and Remote Access for CHAP. By default Msft selects MS-CHAP authentication, which is different.

Additionally, my Windows dial-in account had to have "passwords stored using reversible encryption" enabled in "Active Directory Users and Computers." Then the password must be manually reset, on either the client or server, n order to store it in Windows using reversible encryption.

Finally, back in Routing and Remote Access on the Windows Server, a Remote Access Policy must be created to "Grant remote access permission" for clients using CHAP authentication for NAS-Port-Type Async (Modem), done through the "Policy conditions" properties window for Remote Access Policies, which is part of Routing and Remote Access on the Windows Server.

Then from your Mac, connect using using DOMAIN\username format, with your password and the correct phone number. After much trial and error and research this finally worked and all of our OS X clients are now able to connect to the Windows RRAS. Whew! Good luck. Chad